# Excel VBA - Speed Up Copy Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this macro, which works fine, albeit very slowly. Is there a way to speed it up (perhaps with arrays) so that the whole operation is performed only once?

What my code does is that it filters an Excel Table and then extracts only certain columns and pastes them into another sheet (in a different order).

```
Set lo_b1 = x_bf1.ListObjects(1)
s_date = CLng(ThisWorkbook.Names("in_fre_m").RefersToRange(1, 1))
s_des = ThisWorkbook.Names("dr_no").RefersToRange(1, 1)
s_code = ThisWorkbook.Names("dr_co").RefersToRange(1, 1)
lastrow_d = lo_dr.Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
Set pasterange1 = x_drill.Range("C" & lastrow_d)

    With lo_b1.Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=s_code
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & s_date
    End With

lastrow_s = lo_b1.Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

If lastrow_s > 7 Then
    Set copyrange1 = x_bf1.Range("D8:D" & lastrow_s) 'Date
    Set copyrange2 = copyrange1.Offset(0, 1)  'Description
    Set copyrange3 = copyrange1.Offset(0, 16)  'Calculation
    Set copyrange5 = copyrange1.Offset(0, 5)  'Classification
    Set copyrange6 = copyrange1.Offset(0, 6)  'Notes
    Set copyrange7 = copyrange1.Offset(0, 11) '§
    Set copyrange8 = copyrange1.Offset(0, 12) 'Code
    Set copyrange9 = copyrange1.Offset(0, 20) 'Statutory
    Set copyrange10 = copyrange1.Offset(0, 14) 'Ref


    copyrange10.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Ref
    pasterange1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

    copyrange1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Date
    pasterange1.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

    copyrange5.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Account Name
    pasterange1.Offset(0, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

    copyrange2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Notes
    pasterange1.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

    copyrange8.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Code
    pasterange1.Offset(0, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

    copyrange7.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy '§
    pasterange1.Offset(0, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

    copyrange3.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Calculation
    pasterange1.Offset(0, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

    copyrange9.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Statutory
    pasterange1.Offset(0, 7).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

    copyrange6.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Notes
    pasterange1.Offset(0, 8).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone

    Set copyrange1 = Nothing
    Set copyrange2 = Nothing
    Set copyrange3 = Nothing
    Set copyrange4 = Nothing
    Set copyrange5 = Nothing
    Set copyrange6 = Nothing
    Set copyrange7 = Nothing
    Set copyrange8 = Nothing
    Set copyrange9 = Nothing
    Set copyrange10 = Nothing
    End If
```

Comment: I don't see it in your code, so have you tried adding `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` at start of your code?

Comment: Yes screenupdating is false and calculation are set to manual

Comment: Without re-writing the entire thing, what about Application.EnableEvents?  If that's not set to false, it's very much worth a shot.

Comment: prob suits https://codereview.stackexchange.com better

Answer (score 0):

To add to the comments about screen updating, events and calculation try changing

```
copyrange10.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Ref
pasterange1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
```

to

```
pasterange1.Value=copyrange1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

In my experience it is much faster than copy and paste (and it also prevents issues with another application using the clipboard)

Comment: Yes, it was just an example.  I should have been clearer.  You should do this for each range.